# How to open slideble widget programmatically from the outside in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget

I have a Row of `ListTiles` which have `Slidable` as their children. I need to open the `Slidable` from an action in the `AppBar` (similar to how editing works in apple music). Since this happens outside of the `Slidable` widget, I cannot get the `SlidableState` from `Slidable.of(context)`. Is there a way to do that, or perhaps a similar widget that does the job easier?

Example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar:AppBar(
    title: Text('Title'),
    actions: [
      <EditButton()>, #has to open the slidable
    ],
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
       Slidable: (
         child: ListTile(tile: Text('text'),
         actionPane: SlidableScrollActionPane(),
         actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {delete()}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
          ],
       ),
    ],
  ),
}
```

Comment: Are you using `flutter_slidable`?

Comment: I believe you can do that with the help of Slidable Controller.
https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable/issues/6

Comment: Yes. i am using flutter_slidable. I am creating a custom library, so therefore am not using state management there. I will look into Slidable Controller a bit more, thanks.